# What is this white-and-purple, five-petaled flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

What is the name of this plant? The picture was taken in Central Europe this September. The plant is more than 50 cm high and grew from seeds in a single season.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [*Malva sylvestris* 'Zebrina'](http://www.waysidegardens.com/zebrina-hollyhock-mallow/p/43931/), commonly known as Mallow Zebrina - these are perennials that happen to flower in their first year, hardy in [USDA hardiness zones](http://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov/PHZMWeb/InteractiveMap.aspx) 4-8. Easily raised from seed, the streaking on the petals can be deep pink, pale pink, maroon - there is considerable variation in the coloration.